# Confused regarding parameters and constructors in Java

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

So basically, I have an assignment where I have many different things to do. I am stuck on this part where I have to create three different constructors which takes different parameters.

Parameters:

1. Takes parameters for all 4 fields - which I think I did in the constructor below.
2. One parameter for address line 1-3 and the postcode.
3. Parameter for address line 1 and 2 and postcode.

I have tried making different constructors with different parameters but it won't work, so any insight into this would be greatly appreciated it.

```
class Address{

    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private String addressLine3;
    private String addressLine4;
    private String postcode;

    public Address(String allFields){
        this.addressLine1 = allFields;
        this.addressLine2 = allFields;
        this.addressLine3 = allFields;
        this.addressLine4 = allFields;
        
        
     }
}
```

Edit: Here is the original question regarding this stage of the exercise.

3. Give the class three different constructors: one which takes parameters for all four fields, one which takes parameters for only address lines 1-3 and the postcode, and one which takes parameters for only address lines 1 and 2 and the postcode. The constructors that leave out some fields should set those fields to contain an empty string value "".

Thank you.

Comment: You can define multiple constructors with different parameters, but if both (2) and (3) expect two string parameters, they can not be differentiated.

Comment: I don't think the way you solved 1. is correct, after all it says the constructor should take **"parameters"** (plural) for all 4 fields, not a single parameter that gets assigned to all fields.

Comment: what you have done doesn't make any sense.Because you are iniitilizing the same value to all addressLine attributes.I think you need to have a constructor with multiple parameters.(Regarding the implemented constructor)

Comment: Did you copy the constructors requirements literally? Or does that list partly reflect your understanding of the assignment? Because the wording given in your question results in quite an advanced assignment, which might not be your instructor's intent. if I'm right, feel free to add the original wording to the question.

Comment: '_..all **4** fields" is a little confusing, given that the `Address` object actually has **five** fields (the four address lines, and postcode).

Comment: I have added the original question to make it clearer.

Comment: That original question makes more sense than your re-worded one, although there's still the "all four fields" issue which should probably have been given as "all five fields".

Answer (score 0):

1. Takes parameters for all 4 fields - which I think I did in the constructor below.

```
    public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String addressLine3, String addressLine4){
       this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
       this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
       this.addressLine3 = addressLine3;
       this.addressLine4 = addressLine4;
    }
```

2. One parameter for address line 1-3 and the postcode.

```
public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String addressLine3, String postCode){
       this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
       this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
       this.addressLine3 = addressLine3;
       this.postCode = postCode;
    }
```

3. Parameter for address line 1 and 2 and postcode.

```
public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String postCode){
           this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
           this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;    
           this.postCode = postCode;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your original question answer should be like below.In your original question it's saying to implement "one which takes parameters for all four fields" So **I will consider the four fields as adressLine fields** ,because there are 5 fields already available including postcode field.

**Extra:please follow the naming convetions in Java when your are naming the varibles.Ex: postcode should be postCode,try to avoid numbers in variable names**

```
public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String addressLine3, String addressLine4){//Here I considered the four fields as addressLine attributes
       this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
       this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
       this.addressLine3 = addressLine3;
       this.addressLine4 = addressLine4;
       this.postcode ="";
    }
```

```
public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String addressLine3, String postcode){
       this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
       this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
       this.addressLine3 = addressLine3;
       this.addressLine4 = "";
       this.postcode = postcode;
    }
```

```
public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String postcode){
           this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
           this.addressLine2 = addressLine2; 
           this.addressLine3 = "";
           this.addressLine4 = "";
           this.postcode = postcode;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From you question you are going to `set value to all variables` in all constructors. For this scenario of calling internal constructors, Java provides a method `this()`. So, the following should be the right combination.

```
class Address{
    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private String addressLine3;
    private String addressLine4;
    private String postcode;

    //1. one which takes parameters for only address lines 1 and 2 and the postcode
    public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String postCode){
        this(addressLine1, addressLine2, "", postCode);
    }

    //2. one which takes parameters for only address lines 1-3 and the postcode
    public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String addressLine3, String postCode){
        this(addressLine1, addressLine2, addressLine3, "");
        this.postcode = postCode;
    }
        
    //3. one which takes parameters for all four fields, 
    public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String addressLine3, String addressLine4){
       super();
       this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
       this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
       this.addressLine3 = addressLine3;
       this.addressLine4 = addressLine4;
    }
}
```